# Making a lot of request for the facebook graph

Tags: php, facebook

Basically I enabled the facebook comment plugin on a website.
Now with graph.facebook.com I would like to index those comment. To do that I can parse the json given by:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[myurl]
```

The problem is that I will send a lot of request (1 for each page that has the fb comment plugins)

Is there a way to do such operation without encountering a flood control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple urls (separated by `,`) to the Graph API to get data for several objects like this:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[myurl],[myurl2],[myurln]
```

To override limit on url length you can issue POST request and passing `ids` not in the url:

```
POST http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?method=get
POST DATA: ids=[myurl],[myurl2],[myurln]
```

Comment: Facebook do push some limits on rate of requests and number of objects you can get data for. I'm not really know the actual numbers but requesting data for 50-70 objects works ok for me...

Comment: You wrote method=get in the POST example, i think it's method=POST ?

Comment: I have a problem, trying to do this post request now facebook replies: "An access token is required to request this resource" oO

Comment: Nope, it's `method=get` which instruct Graph API to shave like in a GET method but using POST in real. You can use your application `access_token` if it's required.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I was losing my mind because i stupidly changed it to method=post, and facebook was requiring me some user permissions =/. Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As long as you pace yourself - leave a couple seconds between requests, perhaps - you'll be fine. Apps like Zynga's are presumably sending thousands of Graph API requests per second.

Comment: Zynga makes billions too, so maybe they are whitelisted somewhere