# Access token for facebook POST request?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to crawl the comments left on my own website.

With a get request like this: `http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[url]`

I have no problem, but If i try to send a post request with the same param facebook replies:

```
"An access token is required to request this resource"
```

Someone knows why? And how to obtain such token for something that is already public (comments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer in response to your comment: "I don't want to publish a comment. I jsut want to read those comments with a post request". A POST request by default is how you publish new comments. To just view the comments using a POST request you have to tell it to treat it as a GET request by adding `method=get` to the query string. So POST to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?method=get
```

And make your post body:

```
ids=[x],[y],[z]
```

*(Also be aware that this `method=get` works here because Facebook implemented that as an option. In general, HTTP doesn't supply that option.)*

Comment: Perfect answer, It was not working because i stupidly changed method = POST. Now it works

Comment: It is working now, but after about ~50 urls facebook gives me:
`error: type: "Exception", message: "Unknown identifier, "`

Comment: Ok I found the prolbem, it seems i just need to retry the request and the error is gone... it seems some random error by facebook

Answer (score 2):

Those comments may be public, but the ability to post a new comment requires authentication.

Facebook uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication, and you obtain an access token as described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. There are a multiple options to obtain it (for server-side or client-side) and how you want to do that is highly dependent on the specifics of your application.

Once you have it, you can just add it to the query string:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?access_token=[token]&ids=[url]
```

Comment: Thanks ben, But I don't want to publish a comment. I jsut want to read those comments with a post request http://stackoverflow.com/a/8596068/496223